# Textview text appears on Selection for copy or cut

Tags: ios, uitextview

[In this image i have the title New Wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALOVT.png) I have a textview which is being set programmatically. It displays the text when respective view controller is appears but when an alert appears the text disappears and appears if try to select the text of the textview.

[Now when the alert appears the text disappears although i'm not setting anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGjrA.png)

Comment: Can you please share screen shot?

Comment: or at least some code ?

Comment: might be if you using custom alert it is tinting your UIWindow

Comment: I have added the link for the first and the second screen shot of the scenario.

Comment: is it UILable or UITextField?

Comment: textfield @Dheeraj